How to use latest SkiaSharp in Debian 10 (buster)
ASP.NET 9 MVC application is running in Debian 10 (buster) server. It use captcha
https://github.com/VahidN/DNTCaptcha.Core
nuget package whose latest version requires Skiasharp 3.116.1
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies/3.116.1
After upgrading to SkiaSharp to latest version 3.116.1
in NuGet running application throws error
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKData' threw an exception.
---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/www/myapp/libSkiaSharp.so)
libSkiaSharp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/var/www/myapp/liblibSkiaSharp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/var/www/myapp/libSkiaSharp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/var/www/myapp/liblibSkiaSharp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

  at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_data_new_empty()
  at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_data_new_empty()  at SkiaSharp.SKData..cctor()
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at SkiaSharp.SKData.Create(IntPtr address, Int32 length)
  at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
  at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(Byte[] buffer)
....

How to run SkiaSharp in Debian 10 (buster)? Previous version
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies/3.116.0
does not throw exception and works.

I found various other people using .NET on Linux running into the error "version 'GLIBC_2.29' not found". Also found a page with a potential fix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/236856/microsoft-app-service-error-version-glibc-2-29-not. Summarizing: you should set SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT with value = true which supposedly helps to install the required dependencies. I can't test it for you; perhaps if it works you can write your own answer with all the details (which I don't know or have).

It looks like SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT is available in Azure only. I'm using Publish command in Visual Studio with Target Runtime linux-x64 and Deployment Mode Self contained. How to use this fix without Azure?
